# Android commands converted to Swift 4 for Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, swift, firebase, analytics

I'm following the documentation for sending screen names to Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager and Firebase per this [article](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/10/18/firebase-analytics-for-apps/).

However, I am testing in Swift but the example is in Android Java code.

What is the Swift 4 equivalent of the first two lines below?

```
Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
params.putString("screen_name", name); 
Analytics.logEvent("screenview", params);
```

Thanks

Comment: Basically I'm looking to see what the Swift equivalent of the Bundle object is. Is it Dictionary? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the iOS documentation which will show you code similar to this:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
  AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(title!)",
  AnalyticsParameterItemName: title!,
  AnalyticsParameterContentType: "cont"
  ])
```

Or

```
Analytics.logEvent("share_image", parameters: [
  "name": name as NSObject,
  "full_text": text as NSObject
  ])
```

Link: [iOS Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events)